# Combobox Binding To Value

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, combobox

```
    [Display(Name = "Type of Delivery:",
        Description = "(TBC)")]
    public string DeliveryType
    {
        get { return _deliveryType; }
        set
        {
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                                       new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                                           {MemberName = CalculatorParameters.GetPropertyName()});
            _deliveryType = value;
        }
    }





    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=v_DeliveriesOrderedDomainDataSource, Path=Data}"  SelectedItem="{Binding DeliveryType, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" Margin="12,12"/>
```

this works fine, except that the value bound is a ToString() of my object v_DeliveriesOrdered, but I would like to use a specific field
ie: value is "V_DeliveriesOrdered : {US,U.S.A. Port of Entry}" whereas I would like to use the field code which value is just US

What should I do? (rather than taking whatever is inbetween the '{' and ','

Comment: "Use a specific value" you mean as the display value?

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I replaced the DomainServices by a regular Silverlight WCF service, and the problem disappeared